# CSS Transitions: One not working after the other

Tags: css, html, slide, transition

I have two CSS tranistions as below (they both cover the page and then slide off, one after the other):

```
  $('#div1').transition({ x: '-1500px', delay: 800 }, 1000);
  $('#div2').transition({ x: '-1500px', delay: 1600 }, 1000);
```

the first one works fine, but the 2nd doesnt. Naturally I have checked all CSS and names:

```
#div1 {
    background-color: #000;
    z-index: 99;
    position:absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#div2 {
    background-color: #fff;
    z-index: 90;
    position:absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%
}
```

Can anyone help me out? Thanks!

Comment: Umm, that isn't a CSS Transition, for information on CSS3 Transitions please see: http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_transitions.asp

Comment: what effect are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @DexterHuinda Im trying to have 2 divs cover the screen and then slide away, one after the other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this is the effect you want: http://jsfiddle.net/Nr7nJ/

I changed div2's background-color to red, since the browser by default uses white bg.

Comment: yeah thats exactly what I want....and what I have written. Hmm,its just not working for me...Ill have to re-examine the code